# Vertical to Horizontal Google App Script Index Result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, linkedin-api

I came across an interesting way to combine CSE (Custom Search Engine) and PSE (Programmable Search Engine) and use it as a function in Sheets using the following AppScripts code:

[Article Link](https://medium.com/@giacomo_io/how-to-get-linkedin-profiles-in-google-sheets-with-a-formula-6d997e82abbd)  Credits < the great Giacomo Melzi >

> [Code](https://github.com/giacomo-io/google-sheet-linkedin-formula/blob/main/linkedin.js) <

Now , on passing '0' as the value for 'index' parameter, the results are displayed vertically.

Can anyone change it to display the results horizontally across the same row using some code in Google App Script?

I expect someone to answer this soon, Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with `=TRANSPOSE(LINKEDINPROFILE(A3,0))`